# My ReactJs locahlost keeps refreshing every second in my Mac

Tags: node.js, reactjs, webpack, proxy, gulp

I am working in company project and running my project ReactJs app using gulp
From last few months when ever i am trying to access localhost using URL
https://localhost.comapny.com:8443/
its keep refreshing every second
even if i have not done any code changes still it keeps refreshing every second(some days it will not be refreshing like this in mozilla browser) and i can see this below  error this my terminal from where i had run gulp

`[HPM] Error occurred while trying to proxy request /node_modules/olt-global-styles/images/halflings.png? from localhost.homedepot.com:8443 to https://localhost.company.com:8443/ (ECONNRESET)` (https://nodejs.org/api/errors.html#errors_common_system_errors)

[image]

[image]

But this same project code is working for all of my colleagues without any issues.

Comment: Has this always been an issue with your project? If not, what recent changes have been made since this issue has started to happen?

Comment: this use to happen sometmes before, now it became consistent and happening always. Not able to work. Dont know wt has changed

Comment: This can happen from unnecessary re-renders, infinite loops, or even weird redirect settings. Is there any more information you could give?

Also, is there a reason you're on node v10?

Comment: my prject only works in node 8 or 10 version itseems, so i am using this version.

Comment: I feel its something to do proxy, but not able to figure out , what is that. I tried being connected to my office vpn and also tried being disconnected from VPN , in both cases, it keeps refreshing